# Cannot get RubyMine 5.4 to install Gems

Tags: rubygems, rubymine

I have built a rails app in BBEDIT and iTerm2 and I have now opened it in RubyMine 5.4.  It tells me I have missing gems and to run bundler install to install them.  When I do this is the response I get:

/Users/ericbrooke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/ericbrooke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/Users/ericbrooke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/cache/rake-10.0.4.gem] in /Users/ericbrooke/rails_projects/shipping
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Process finished with exit code 5

Comment: Did you manage to solve it or find a workaround for it? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with a different gem, and it turned out to be a server issue.

Trying again at a later time solved it.